# How to host more than 65536 services, each requiring a distinct port?

Tags: docker, networking, deployment, sdn

I want to host web services (say a simple nodejs api service)

There is a limitation on the number of services that I can host on a single host, since the number of ports available on a host is only 65536.

I can think of having a `virtual sub-network` that is visible only within the host and then have a `proxy server` that sits on the host and routes the APIs to the appropriate web-service.

Is it possible to do this with dockers - where each service is deployed in a container, a proxy server routing the APIs to the appropriate container?

Is there any off the shelf solution for this (preferably free of cost).

Comment: you could create another Virtual Machine with new IP and all ports available... you can also use unix sockets (unix://) rather than http:// service mapping

Comment: I do not want to create more than one VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I doubt you can run 65536 processes per host, unless it's huge. Anyway, I would not recommend that because of availability and performance. Too many processes will be competing for the same resources, leading to a lot of context switches. That said, it's doable.

If your services are HTTP you can use a reverse proxy, like nginx or [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/). If not, you can use [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) for TCP services. Traefik is a better option because it performs service discovery, so you won't need to configure the endpoints manually.

In this setup the networking should be `bridge`, which is the default in Docker. Every container will have its own IP address, so you won't have any problem regarding port exhaustion.